# Initializing Dynamically allocated integer

Tags: c, initialization, malloc, expression, declaration

I guess dynamically created variable has to be initialized separately and not at the time of allocating. Why the below line of code does not compile?
Why do I get the error message " expected ')' before 'p'".

`*(int *p = malloc(sizeof(int))) = 23;`

|

Comment: You can initialize to zero with `calloc()`

Comment: I agree. But my main point here was the reason for the error message and I guess @chqrlie gave reason for that

Comment: Note that "initialization" has specific meaning in C, and the semantics are different in some ways from assignment.  The variable here is `p`, and that is initialized in your example code.  I'm not sure offhand if using something like `calloc()` as @pmg noted fits the language-lawyer defintion of variable initialization in C, but if it doesn't there's simply no way to formally "initialize" any dynamically-allocated object in C - you have to *assign* the value.  And again, that's because "assignment" is not the same as "initialization".

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I agree calling "initialization" to the space allocated by `calloc()` might be twisting the 'language-lawyer' aspect. Though [C11 7.22.3.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.2) says in p2: "... The space is initialized to all bits zero."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int))
```

is a declaration of the variable `p`.

You may not use declarations like an expression.

So you need to split this line

```
*(int *p = malloc(sizeof(int))) = 23;
```

in two lines like

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

and

```
*p = 23;
```

Another way is at first to declare the variable `p`

```
int *p;
```

and then to use the declared variable in the expression

```
*( p = malloc( sizeof( int ) ) ) = 23;
```

Answer (score 5):

The definition `int *p` cannot appear inside an expression, it is a syntax error. You must use a definition and a separate expression to initialize the contents:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
*p = 23;
```

or

```
int *p;
*(p = malloc(sizeof(int))) = 23;
```

Note that both of the above forms have undefined behavior in case of memory allocation failure.